# Filter array if isnt empty - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am calling filterArray function from multiple location, which has the main array. So for the first time when i call, my array will have 4 items then i have some condition which filters it off to 2 items. Next time when i call same filterArray function, i should filter from already filtered items, not from the parent array

Basically this is my parent array `arr`

```
{
    "0" : a
    "1" : b
    "2" : c
    "3" : d
}
```

Next i am doing

```
var newArray = [];
filterArray(tick)
{
    for(var k = 0;k<arr.length;k++){ 
        if(tick == true)
        {
            newArray.push(arr[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

newArray is

```
{
    "0" : a
    "1" : b 
}
```

Again new filter should work on the filtered array

```
for(var k = 0;k<newArray.length;k++)
{ 
    if(tick == true)
    {
        newArray should be
        {
            "0" : a         
        }

     }
}
```

This is what i am doing

```
if (typeof newArray == 'undefined' && newArray.length < 0) 
{   
    newArray = arr;
}
```

how do i filter array items from already filtered array, if present

Comment: Your `arr` is not an array

Comment: `if(index == 0 && index == 1)` can never succeed. How can the same variable be equal to two different numbers at the same time? And where is the `index` variable, anyway? Should that be `k`?

Comment: your script is buggy, `index is not defined`, etc...

Comment: Your function should return the filtered array instead of using global variables. Then you can write `arr = filterArray(arr);` to replace the array. Also, do you know about the standard `Array.prototype.filter()` function?

Comment: What is `tick` ? How can the array be filtered ? If `tick` is true then you will have the same array. If it is false, you will have an empty array

Comment: tick is some ramdom condition.. filter should work based in that condition..  not sure abt the Array.prototype.filter() @Barmar

Comment: @Matarishvan Look it up, it's exactly what you need instead of writing your own function. It takes the array and a callback function as arguments, and returns a new array with the elements that the callback function return truthy for.

Comment: @Matarishvan Do you know that you have an OBJECT and not an ARRAY ?

Answer (score -1):

Use below function which will take array as input and will return filtered array as output.

```
function filterArray(myArray)
{
    var newArray = [];
    if(myArray && myArray.length > 0)
    {
        for(var k = 0; k < myArray.length; k++)
        { 
            if(index == 0 && index == 1)
            {
                newArray.push(myArray[k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```